# DataTable is not getting decimal value of an item via json

Tags: java, json, datatable

I have a database where i have stored some values in double format and i am populating those values via json to the datatable.but data is coming in proper format from the database.But when it is coming through json it is not getting the proper value, i.e the decimal part is missing.

```
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 

                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        var csrfGrd='<csrf:token-name/>=<csrf:token-value/>';
                        //var sessionId=document.getElementById("sessionId").value;
                        //alert(sessionId);
                        var url='${pageContext.request.contextPath}'+'/getCategoryTree.do?'+csrfGrd;

                            $('#example').dataTable( { 
                                "processing": true,
                                "serverSide": true,
                                "ajax": url,
                                "columns": [
                                    {"data" : "code"},        
                                    { "data": "description"},
                                    { "data": "url"},
                                    {"data" : "model"},
                                    {"data" : "mrp"}

                                    ],
                                 "columnDefs": [
                                             {
                                                 "targets": [ 0 ],
                                                 "visible": true,
                                                 "searchable": false,
                                                 "sortable" :false

                                             },
                                          {
                                                 "targets": [ 3 ],
                                                 "visible": true,
                                                 "searchable": false
                                             }
                                         ], 

                                      "aoColumnDefs": [
                                                    { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [0,1,2,3,4] }
                                                  ] ,       
                                 "rowCallback": function( row, data ) {
                                     $("td:eq(0)",row).html("<a href='"+data.url+"' target='_new'>"+data.code+"<//a/> ");
                                     //alert(data.parentCategoryId);
                                        /* $('td:eq(6)', row).html( '<input type="checkbox" name="selectedIds" value="'+data.id+'" />' ).attr("class","checkIds");
                                        $('td:eq(0)',row).attr('id','_'+data.id); */
                                 }

                            });
                    });
   function addToItem(){
               $("input[name='selectedIds']:checked").each(function(){
                  // alert($(this).parent().parent().html());
                  // alert($(this).parent().parent());
                  var tdID=$(this).parent().parent().find("td:first-child").attr("id");
                  var itemCount=$("#itemList>tbody").find("#"+tdID).length;
                  if(itemCount==0){
                    $("#itemList>tbody").append("<tr class='even'>"+$(this).parent().parent().html()+"<//tr>").find(".checkIds").remove(".checkIds");
                  }else{
                  alert("ITEM "+$(this).parent().parent().find("td:first-child").html()+" is already added ");
                  }
               });      
     }
   function getCatalog(actionName){
       document.catalogForm.action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/"+actionName+".do";
       document.catalogForm.submit();
     }
   function saveCategory(){
       var categories;
       $("#itemList>tbody").find("tr").each(function(){
            var index=$(this).find("td").attr("id").substr(1);
            if($("input[id='_del_"+index+"']").attr("checked")!="checked"){
                $("form[name='catalogForm']").append("<input type='hidden' name='subCategoryId' value='"+index+"'  />");
            }
       })
       document.catalogForm.action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/updateCategoryCatalogMapping.do";
       document.catalogForm.submit(); 
   }
  </script>  

 <script type="text/javascript" src="<html:rewrite page='/js/metal.js'/>"></script>
<div class="errorDiv"><html:errors/></div>              
    <table id="example" class="display"   style="width: 100%;text-align: center;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Item Code</th>
                    <th>Item Description </th>
                    <th>URL</th>
                    <th>MODEL </th>
                    <th>LAST UPDATED MRP</th>


                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
    </table>
```

can any one help me i am setting the dataa in the action with this

```
DataTableJsonObject dat=new DataTableJsonObject();
    List <CategoryObject> catlist=catalogService.getCategoryTree(storeId,catSearch,dat);
    CategoryObject cat=new CategoryObject();
    UserObject user=new UserObject();
    dat.setData(catlist);
    JSON json=JSONSerializer.toJSON(dat);
    //JSON json=JSONArray.fromObject(user);

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
    out.print(json.toString()); 
    System.out.println("json:"+json.toString());
    response.setContentType("application/json");;
```

Comment: my mrp column is showing only integer value which should be double